# `mindmap` package: concept color does not fade

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I'm trying to follow the $6^{th}$ tutorial of the [pgf manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). I managed to create the mindmap, but I cannot correctly fade colors from one to another:

[image]

this is the code that generated the image (I've included the `mindmap` and `shadows` libraries):

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [mindmap] 
\begin{scope}[
    every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt, circular drop shadow},
    root concept/.append style={concept color=black, fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black, font=\large\scshape},
    text=white,
    computational problems/.style={concept color=red, faded/.style={concept color=red!50}},
    computational models/.style={concept color=blue, faded/.style={concept color=blue!50}},
    measuring complexity/.style={concept color=orange, faded/.style={concept color=orange!50}},
    solving problems/.style={concept color=green!50!black, faded/.style={concept color=green!50!black!50}},
    grow cyclic,
    level 1/.append style={sibling angle=90, level distance=4.5cm, font=\scshape},
    level 2/.append style={sibling angle=45, level distance=3cm, font=\footnotesize},
    ]
    \node[root concept] {Computational Complexity}
        child[computational problems] { node {Computational Problems}
            child { node {Problem Measures} }
            child { node {Problem Aspects} }
            child { node[concept color=blue] {Problem Domains} }
            child { node {Key Problems} }
        }
        child[computational models] { node {Computational Models}
            child { node {Turing Machines} }
            child { node[faded] {Random-Access Machines} }
            child { node {Circuits} }
            child { node[faded] {Binary Decision Diagrams} }
            child { node {Oracle Machines} }
            child { node {Programming in Logic} }
        }
        child[measuring complexity] { node {Measuring Complexity}
            child { node {Complexity Measures} }
            child { node {Classifying Complexity} }
            child { node {Comparing Complexity} }
            child { node[faded] {Describing Complexity} }
        }
        child[solving problems] { node {Solving Problems}
            child { node {Exact Algorithms} }
            child { node {Randomization} }
            child { node {Fixed-Parameter Algorithms} }
            child { node {Parallel Computation } }
            child { node {Partial Solutions} }
            child { node {Approximation} }
        };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is identical to the code that is presented on the manual (I've also tried to copy and paste the code on the manual without any success).

Has anyone have any idea for why I cannot reproduce the behavior displayed in the manual (i.e. "fading" between different concept colors)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the options to the node, not to the child. If you correct this, you get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [mindmap] 
\begin{scope}[
    every node/.style={concept, execute at begin node=\hskip0pt, circular drop shadow},
    root concept/.append style={concept color=black, fill=white, line width=1ex, text=black, font=\large\scshape},
    text=white,
    computational problems/.style={concept color=red, 
    faded/.style={concept color=red!50}},
    computational models/.style={concept color=blue, 
    faded/.style={concept color=blue!50}},
    measuring complexity/.style={concept color=orange, faded/.style={concept color=orange!50}},
    solving problems/.style={concept color=green!50!black, faded/.style={concept color=green!50!black!50}},
    grow cyclic,
    level 1/.append style={sibling angle=90, level distance=4.5cm, font=\scshape},
    level 2/.append style={sibling angle=45, level distance=3cm, font=\footnotesize},
    ]
    \node[root concept] {Computational Complexity}
        child[computational problems] { node {Computational Problems}
            child { node {Problem Measures} }
            child { node {Problem Aspects} }
            child[concept color=blue] { node {Problem Domains} }
            child { node {Key Problems} }
        }
        child[computational models] { node {Computational Models}
            child { node {Turing Machines} }
            child[faded] { node {Random-Access Machines} }
            child { node {Circuits} }
            child[faded] { node {Binary Decision Diagrams} }
            child { node {Oracle Machines} }
            child { node {Programming in Logic} }
        }
        child[measuring complexity] { node {Measuring Complexity}
            child { node {Complexity Measures} }
            child { node {Classifying Complexity} }
            child { node {Comparing Complexity} }
            child[faded] { node {Describing Complexity} }
        }
        child[solving problems] { node {Solving Problems}
            child { node {Exact Algorithms} }
            child { node {Randomization} }
            child { node {Fixed-Parameter Algorithms} }
            child { node {Parallel Computation } }
            child { node {Partial Solutions} }
            child { node {Approximation} }
        };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is planned to make this distinction more explicit [in future versions of the pgfmanual](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/848).